# Catch Error Message in PowerBI Text Enhancer Visual and return custom Message

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I used the Text Enhancer by MAQ Software to display answers from a survey. I used this measure to filter the answer by a selected customer id:
`Is_filtered = IF(ISFILTERED(CALCULATE_DATA_PI_ICH[process_instance_id]), min(CALCULATE_DATA_PI_ICH[process_instance_id]),0)`
if the user has an answer selected befor in the survey everything works fine, but if this is not the case the Text Enhancer Visual returns an **Query contains null values** Error because my measure filtered down to an empty table. How can i avoid this and print for example "No answer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this to avoid blank values :

```
Is_filtered = 
VAR Result = IF(ISFILTERED(CALCULATE_DATA_PI_ICH[process_instance_id]), min(CALCULATE_DATA_PI_ICH[process_instance_id]),0)
RETURN IF(ISBLANK(Result), "No answer", Result)
```

If the VAR returns an empty table, it will return "No answer" instead and should also avoid the "Query contains null values" error

Comment: I think I expressed myself incorrectly. The measure always returns a correct value (the ID of the user). With this ID I filter a table with answers. If the user has given an answer, the table is filtered on this answer. But if the user didn't give an answer the table is empty after filtering on his ID and the visual shows "Query contains null values" and I want to avoid this error message and replace it.

Comment: It might be specific to this custom visual then. One turnaround would be to force return one fictive value "No answer" that you might add in your dataset. 
Like add manually a line with a fictive user ID with the other columns "No answer" and in the DAX, check if the User ID exists, if not, you should redirect to that fictive user ID. 
It's not ideal but it could work